# Hibernate - How to retrieve a list of all entity classes which have been configured for L2 Caching

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I would like to know how to retrieve a list of all entity classes which have been configured for L2 caching in Hibernate.

It would be preferable if I could retrieve this from the SessionFactory class (http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/SessionFactory.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
for ( EntityPersister persister : ( (SessionFactoryImplementor) sessionFactory ).getEntityPersisters().values() ) {
    if ( persister.hasCache() ) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks a lot Steve.  This is extremely helpful to this Hibernate noob.